# Still getting NullPointerException even if using Optional<>

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am trying to use Optional<> to keep an check on nullpointexception and incase it happens then some otherthing to print.
(https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

I am setting soundcard to null, and still i am getting nullpointerexception, but i want to avoid it with optional.

**Main Class (Computer)**

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Computer {
    public Optional<SoundCard> getSoundcard() {
        return soundcard;
    }

    public void setSoundcard(Optional<SoundCard> soundcard) {
        this.soundcard = soundcard;
    }

    private Optional<SoundCard> soundcard = null ;


    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
         Optional<Computer> computer = Optional.of(new Computer());;


        String verion = computer.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
            .flatMap(SoundCard::getUsb)
            .map(USB::getVersion)
            .orElse("Unknown");
        System.out.println(verion);
    }
}
```

**Another class SoundCard**

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class SoundCard {

    public Optional<USB> getUsb() {
        return usb;
    }

    public void setUsb(Optional<USB> usb) {
        this.usb = usb;
    }

    private Optional<USB> usb = null;
}
```

**Another Class (USB)**

```
public class USB {

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    private String version;
}
```

Any hint or help is welcome :)

Comment: just initialize the variable `Optional<Computer> computer ;`

Comment: that is because it isn't initialized.  => Optional<Computer> computer ;
         Computer computer1 = new Computer();

        String verion = computer.Stream().flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)

Also, it is stream(), not Stream()

Comment: Variable computer is not initialized. It means you have to create optional of computer or create empty optional. For example Optional<Computer> computer = Optional.of(new Computer()) or Optional<Computer> computer = Optional.empty(). I’m not sure if Optionals have method stream(), but if it’s true, it have to start with lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

```
// computer initialization
Optional<Computer> computer = Optional.of(new Computer());

// Applying operations to Optional<Computer>: stream() is for Collections, not for Optionals
String version = computer.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
            .flatMap(SoundCard::getUsb)
            .map(USB::getVersion)
            .orElse("Unknown");
```

UPDATED

In addition, fields like `Computer.soundcard` (having type `Optional`) should not be initialized with `null` value but using `Optional.empty()`, in order to avoid `NullPointerException` or similar errors...

So the full code is

```
public class Computer {
    public Optional<SoundCard> getSoundcard() {
        return soundcard;
    }

    public void setSoundcard(Optional<SoundCard> soundcard) {
        this.soundcard = soundcard;
    }

    private Optional<SoundCard> soundcard = Optional.empty() ;


    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
        Optional<Computer> computer = Optional.of(new Computer());

        String version = computer
                .flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
                .flatMap(SoundCard::getUsb)
                .map(USB::getVersion)
                .orElse("Unknown");
        System.out.println(version);
    }
}

class SoundCard {

    public Optional<USB> getUsb() {
        return usb;
    }

    public void setUsb(Optional<USB> usb) {
        this.usb = usb;
    }

    private Optional<USB> usb = Optional.empty();
}

class USB {

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    private String version;
}
```

Comment: Actually I would delete mine in favor of this.

Comment: but when i make soundcard to null , then it throws nullpointerexception , but i am using optional to to not see a null pointerexception, please help.

Comment: @Raam Never set an `Optional` to `null`. Use [`Optional.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--)

Comment: I think the problem is in classes `Computer` and `SoundCard`: where a fielf (like `Computer`.soundcard` is an optional, it should not be valorized as `null` but as `Optional.empty()`. I update my response including all classes...

Comment: @TiiJ7 , DOC says `Optional can be thought of a single-value container that either contains a value or is empty.` but if i assign null to **soundcard** i am not getting any compilation error but a nullpointerException, why??

Comment: @Raam Well, `Optional` is just a class like any other so of course you could assign `null` to it and it will compile. But the idea behind the `Optional` class is to avoid having to assign `null`, which is what causes `NullPointerException`s in the first place. So instead it provides its own `empty()` method which you should use whenever you need to represent a missing value.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the computer variable:

```
Optional<Computer> computer = Optional.of(new Computer());
```

The way you did, `computer` is really not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Java 8, here's the javadoc of `Optional` class, this is what it says:

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a
>   value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return
>   the value.

Now, `stream()` is something that works on a collection of objects and not a single object. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) the documentation for `stream()`:

> Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source. Basically, you need to have a `List<Computer>` in order to call `stream()`, do the filtering and return `Optional<Computer>` by `find` method(s).

As you are trying to call `stream()` on a single object and not a collection, it shows an error.

Also, calling any method on a non instantiated variable in java will always yield compilation error, e.g.:

```
Optional<Computer> computer ;
computer.stream(); // compilation error
```

So, we need to initialise it first and make sure we are calling the correct method based on the type of reference.

Comment: actually, he's calling Stream() on a non-instantiated variable, which is the (first and second) issue

Comment: Do note, `Optional` since Java-9 has `stream()` as well.

Comment: @Stultuske nullpointer thanks for your inputs, I have updated the answer.